# Simple Date Countdown - Android

Tags: android, date, countdown

I'm trying to create a Countdown for Day 12 and Month 06, but I don't know how to do. What I have is:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

// set because java calendar starts in 0       
month = month + 1;

//Lefting months           
int leftMonth = 06 - mes;

//Lefting days
int leftDay = 12 - dia;

text.setText("Faltam " + leftMonth + " Meses e " + leftDay + " Dias");
```

Can anyone help me?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)   {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
  //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
 }
 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}
.start();
```

about countDown timer more detail you can read [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

First of all you must know how much of milesecunds to your Date.

```
Date date=new Date();
System.out.println(date.getTime()); //this will return miliseconds from 1970 year to now
String str = "Jun 13 2023 23:11:52.454 UTC";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
Date date = df.parse(str);
long epoch = date.getTime();//this will return miliseconds from 1970 to  Jun 13 2023
```

Comment: I want to countdown day and months for 06/12/14, but I'm getting days with results like -17..

Comment: do you know a way to convert the date into miliseconds??

Answer (score 0):

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library makes this date-time calculation work *much* easier.

Joda-Time offers the [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) and [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) classes for defining a span of time between two moments. The [PeriodFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) describse that span in units of years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. You can define your own formatss with [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html), but the built-in ones will probably suffice. Joda-Time even helps to localize by using the Java [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );

// Calculate time until the new year.
DateTime target = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

Period period = new Period( now, target );
```

Render a representation in text of various languages…

```java
// Using default language of this Java Virtual Machine.
PeriodFormatter formatter = PeriodFormat.getDefault();
String output = formatter.print( period );

// Using French language.
PeriodFormatter formatterEnFrançais = PeriodFormat.wordBased( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String outputEnFrançais = formatterEnFrançais.print( period );

// Using Portugese language.
PeriodFormatter formatterPortugese = PeriodFormat.wordBased( Locale.forLanguageTag( "pt" ) );
String outputPortugese = formatterPortugese.print( period );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "outputEnFrançais: " + outputEnFrançais );
System.out.println( "outputPortugese: " + outputPortugese );
```

When run…

```
output: 2 days, 7 hours, 44 minutes, 1 second and 955 milliseconds
outputEnFrançais: 2 jours, 7 heures, 44 minutes, 1 seconde et 955 millisecondes
outputPortugese: 2 dias, 7 horas, 44 minutos, 1 segundo e 955 milissegundos
```

### Caveat

Some people report a slowdown on first call to Joda-Time in Android. Never happens in a [proper Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java) environment, only Android. I do not know the current status of this issue.